# Firebase server side filtering not working with indexOn

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating entries using the below query

```
var newMessageRef = friendlyChat.database.ref().child('dinos').push()
newMessageRef.set({
    height: Math.round(100 * Math.random())
});
```

[image]

My firebase rule is

```
{
  "rules": {      
    "dinos": {
      "$messageId": {
        ".indexOn": "height"
      },
      ".read": "auth !== null",
      ".write": "auth !== null"
    }
  }
}
```

On the web browser, I issue the below query

```
friendlyChat.database.ref('dinos').orderByChild('height').startAt(70).limitToLast(1).on('child_added', (d)=>console.log(d.val()))
```

I get the right output in console as below

```
{height: 99}
```

However, when I inspect the console, I see the entire node downloaded from server as below. Additionally there is a warning for adding .indexOn

Is something wrong in the firebase rules or my query?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the indexOn on higher level node solved.

```
    "dinos": {      
      ".indexOn": "height",
      ".read": "auth !== null",
      ".write": "auth !== null"
    },
```